# Error in for loop using qplot

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2

I am trying to run a loop and don't understand what is wrong with it, but I must have done something wrong with the syntax.

```
for (i in 9:ncol(Site1)) { 
  print(qplot(Site1[,i],snowfree, data=Site1, geom_smooth(method = "loess", size = 1.5))
    [i])
    }
```

It results in a long list of

```
$<NA>
NULL
```

The function works outside of the loop, using simple x and y variables.

Comment: What are you expecting the final `[i]` to do?

Comment: Have you considered using `facet_wrap`? http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_wrap.html

Comment: I get this error message when I omit the [i]                     Error in if (zero_range(from) || zero_range(to)) return(rep(mean(to),  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
Removed 72 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

Comment: will look into facet_wrap, a good idea for producing around 200 graphs?